# react-native run-android fails as react does not use gradle 5.5.1

Tags: android, react-native

After running npm install, when I do react-native run-android, I get the following error.

This problem was initially occurring due to older gradle versions which didn't support Java12. I updated my gradle to version 5.5.1 and modified the environment variables accordingly. It still tries to download gradle-4.4-all.zip. How do I force it to use gradle 5.5.1?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '12.0.1'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Did you changed file ?`wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Answer (score 0):

try to install jdk/jre 12.0.1 version

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by editing the distributionUrl field in gradle-wrapper.properties file